# Strange behaviour Typeahead with remote JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have a very strange behavior I'm trying to understand for the last couple of hours.

I've made a self explaining JSFiddle that [you can find here.](http://jsfiddle.net/md88bgyc/3/)

Stackoverflow doesn't accept jsfiddle without code, so here we go... :

```js
$(function(){
    var $el = $('#typeahead');
    var resultsObj = {};
    var resultsStrings = [];
    var engine = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace, 
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/echo/json/',  
            prepare: function(xhr, settings) {
                settings.dataType = 'json';
                settings.type = 'POST';
                settings.data = {json: fakeSearchForFiddle($el.typeahead('val'))};
                return settings;
            }, 
            transform: function(data) {
                showRawResult(data);

                resultsObj = {};
                resultsStrings = [];

                if ($.isArray(data)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                        resultsObj[data[i].ref] = data[i];
                        resultsStrings.push(data[i].ref);
                    }
                }
                return resultsStrings;
            }
        }
    });
    engine.initialize();

    $el.typeahead({
        highlight: false
    }, {
        name: 'main', 
        source: engine.ttAdapter(), 
        templates: {
        empty: '<div class="empty-message">No result</div>', 
            suggestion: function(data) {
                if (resultsObj[data] !== undefined) {
                    return '<div>'+resultsObj[data].ref+' <span>('+resultsObj[data].details+')</span></div>';
                }
                return '<div>Unknown</div>';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The server returns a JSON array composed of objects containing a "ref" and "details" key.
The goal of this test is to display suggestions with the following syntax :

"result.ref <span>(result.details)</span>"

It works well with 1 result, or two, or more than 5. Otherwise it's completly messed up and I don't understand why.

I've spend several hours trying different things but can't make it work and the documentation is really vague.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** : [I've posted an issue on Github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small modification to the source of typeahead.js because I need this thing to work as soon as possible.

The problem comes from "**typeahead.bundle.js:1719**" :

```js
function async(suggestions) {
    suggestions = suggestions || [];
    if (!canceled && rendered < that.limit) {
        that.cancel = $.noop;
        rendered += suggestions.length;
        that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
        that.async && that.trigger("asyncReceived", query);
    }
}
```

I've replaced :

```js
rendered += suggestions.length;
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
```

by :

```js
suggestions = (suggestions || []).slice(0, that.limit);
rendered = suggestions.length;
that._append(query, suggestions);
```

and it seems to work.. I have no idea of possible side effects of this modification, so I'll post that on the github of typeahead, hoping they'll update the library or explain me what I did wrong.

**EDIT**: [Github issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218)